# Repeating Run Code Snippet row when other answer gets reloaded

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

In a nutshell, this is the problem:

1. You have an answer with a code snippet.
2. There's another answer that just got updated.
3. You see the "an edit has..." message and click on it.
4. The moment, the other answer gets updated, the row with code snippet is doubled.

**Visuals:**

[image: one]

[image: two]

[image: three]

Comment: +1, I'm sure I've seen this before and confused that I couldn't replicate after reloading the page, hah. Have reproduced this bug in the past. Can confirm; is legit.

Comment: @DanielJames Excellent! :)